# How to create JSON object strategy according to a schema with rust proptest?

Tags: testing, rust, property-based-testing, proptest

I'd like to create a JSON strategy using rust [proptest](https://github.com/AltSysrq/proptest/) library. However, I do not want to create an arbitrary JSON. I'd like to create it according to a schema (more specifically, OpenAPI schema). This means that keys of the JSON are known and I do not want to create them using any strategy, but I'd like to create the values using the strategy (pretty-much recursively).

I already implemented the strategy for primitive types, but I do not how to create a JSON object strategy.

I would like the strategy to have the type `BoxedStratedy<serde_json::Value>` or be able to map the strategy to this type because the JSON objects can contain other objects, and thus I need to be able to compose the strategies.

I found a [`HashMapStrategy`](https://altsysrq.github.io/rustdoc/proptest/latest/proptest/collection/struct.HashMapStrategy.html) strategy, however, it can be only created by a [`hash_map`](https://altsysrq.github.io/rustdoc/proptest/latest/proptest/collection/fn.hash_map.html) function that takes two strategies - one for generating keys and one for values. I thought that I could use [`Just`](https://altsysrq.github.io/rustdoc/proptest/latest/proptest/strategy/struct.Just.html) strategy for the keys, but it did not lead anywhere. Maybe  [`prop_filter_map`](https://altsysrq.github.io/rustdoc/proptest/latest/proptest/strategy/trait.Strategy.html#method.prop_filter_map) could be used.

[Here](https://github.com/matusf/openapi-fuzzer/blob/fee7e9376d84eebf33f80e09cf98b7e602497bbb/src/arbitrary.rs) is the code. There are tests too. One is passing because it tests only primitive type and the other is failing since I did not find a way to implement `generate_json_object` function.

I tried this but the types do not match. Instead of a strategy of map from `string` to JSON value, it is a strategy of a map from `string` to `BoxedStrategy`.

```rust
fn generate_json_object(object: &ObjectType) -> BoxedStrategy<serde_json::Value> {
    let mut json_object = serde_json::Map::with_capacity(object.properties.len());
    for (name, schema) in &object.properties {
        let schema_kind = &schema.to_item_ref().schema_kind;
        json_object.insert(name.clone(), schema_kind_to_json(schema_kind));
    }
    Just(serde_json::Value::Object(json_object)).boxed()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can create a vector of strategies, which implements a `Strategy` trait and can be boxed. So to create a `serde_json::Value::Object`, we create a vector of tuples. The first element will be a `Just` of key and the second element will be a boxed strategy of value. The boxed strategy of value can be created by `schema_kind_to_json` function. After we have a vector of tuples which implement a `Strategy`, we can use `.prop_map` to transform it to a `serde_json::Value::Object`.

```rs
fn generate_json_object(object: &ObjectType) -> BoxedStrategy<serde_json::Value> {
    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(object.properties.len());
    for (name, schema) in &object.properties {
        let schema_kind = &schema.to_item_ref().schema_kind;
        vec.push((Just(name.clone()), schema_kind_to_json(schema_kind)));
    }
    vec.prop_map(|vec| serde_json::Value::Object(serde_json::Map::from_iter(vec)))
        .boxed()
}
```